# How do I create exceptions on Wazuh (OSSEC)?

Tags: linux, centos, hids, ossec

I currently have a setup with OSSEC and AIDE running on our servers.

We are currently receiving a daily alert for each agent when AIDE runs and changes audit.log.

I want to make an exception for that, but I still want to be alarmed when other programs change the audit.log file.

Is there any way to do that?